# Microsoft SQL Server stuck at "Install_SQLSupport_CPU64_Action"

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, freeze

While installing SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition, I got stuck at "Install_SQLSupport_CPU64_Action", this happened to me for the second time, once at work and once at home.

After searching online I found no solution.

Comment: Is it a fresh install? It looks like you could have another one, or it was uninstalled fully

Comment: It is a fresh install, this happened to me previously at work a few weeks ago and we didn't find the solution.

And now I'm at home and this happened again.

However, I just figured how to fix this and posted an answer!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The solution:
You will need to browse to this installation path:
`C:\SQLServer2017Media\<YOUR_SQL_ENU>\1033_ENU_LP\x64\Setup`

Then while the setup is stuck at “Install_SQLSupport_CPU64_Action” run
`SQLSUPPORT.msi`

And follow the installation procedure.

Once installed, run the following command in cmd:

`taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq msiserver"`

The SQL Server setup will continue and succeed.

Edit:

**2019** : C:\SQL2019...

**2022** : C:\SQL2022\Developer_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\Setup

if the error code is 0x851a001a, then you need to change the sector size of the hard drives. Here is the guideline for that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

Comment: I tried this but running SQLSUPPORT.msi while sql server installation is running gives me an error saying another installation is in progress.

Comment: Try running the taskkill before and after SQLSUPPORT.msi, this will kill the process that keeps tracks of msi installations.

Comment: "These rituals are not like the normal rituals." Don't know how you arrived at this solution, but it worked first try. 

For those who come after, it seems that SQL Server 2019 unpacks to C:\SQL2019\...

Comment: @snomsnomsnom the main reason i tried this solution is i developed a couple of MSI packages before and i know msiserver cannot run multiple MSI at the same time ( same reason you cannot uninstall multiple MSI at the same time ).

When you task kill, the msi server lose track of what msi are running and it doesnt prevent the 2nd one from starting.

Its kind of ridiculous a microsoft product that big, fails to know that.

Comment: Start your commandline-tool as administrator for it t work. Still works with Express2022

Comment: I had the problem with 2019, and the kill command alone solved it.

Comment: Had the same issue for 2022.  Install path is C:\SQL2022\Developer_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x64\Setup, but the solution worked, thanks.

Comment: Gotta love it when a solution just works.  Works on SQL 2019 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when installing sql server 2016, the taskkill solution not work for me. Therefore, I tried do uninstallation for  SQL Server 2012 Native Client, and install the one in the setup\x64\sqlncli.msi and reinstall the sql server again, and no more issue anymore.